# Why is this set Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

$K$ : Cantor set

$f$ : $[0,1] \to K$

We can write $\displaystyle x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\varepsilon_k}{2^k} \ (\varepsilon_k = 0,1)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ by binary expansion.

Define
$$ f(x)=f \left( \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\varepsilon_k}{2^k} \right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{2\varepsilon_k}{3^k}.$$

Then, prove that $\{f >a \}=\{x\in [0,1] \mid f(x) >a \}$ is Lebesgue measurable for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

If $a< 0,$ $\{ f>a \}=[0,1]$ and it is Lebesgue measurable.

But what about for $0\leqq a$?

I don't know how $\{f >a \}$ is expressed for $0\leqq a$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, your $f$ is not well-defined, since some $x$ have two different binary expansions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function $f$ is increasing.

Therefore $\{x\in[0,1]\mid f(x)>a\}$ is either empty or has the form $(b,1]$ or $[b,1]$ for some constant $b$ that depends on $a$.

Both of $(b,1]$ and $[b,1]$ are obviously Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Why is $f$ increasing?

Comment: @EPA: Intuitively, because if you have $x < y$ and write their binary fraction expansions under each other, then their digits are the same until a point where $x$ has a $0$ and $y$ has a $1$. That means that the _trinary_ expansions of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ have the same trinary digits until a point where $f(x)$ has a $0$ and $f(y)$ has a $2$.

Comment: (Translating this intuitive argument into an rigorous manipulation of the infinite series in the $\varepsilon_k$s is an exercise for the reader).